# Django rest framework serializer for membership Model?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

How do I use Serializer for something like This

```
class Language(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True, max_length=150)

class Helper(BaseModel):
    languages = models.ManyToManyField('Language', blank=True, through="HelperLanguage")

class HelperLanguage(BaseModel):
    helper = models.ForeignKey('Helper', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    language = models.ForeignKey('Language', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    read = models.BooleanField()
    write = models.BooleanField()
    speak = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class LanguageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Language
        fields = ["id", "name"]


class HelperLanguageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    language = LanguageSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = HelperLanguage
        fields = ["id", "language", "read", "write", "speak"]


class HelperPublicSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    languages = HelperLanguageSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
   
    class Meta:
        model = Helper
        fields = ['id', 'languages']
```

while using HelperPublicSerialiser for list view I am getting error

Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `read` on serializer `HelperLanguageSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Language` instance.
I do understand the problem but couldn't find any solution probably not using membership model right way.

Comment: Your `source` should be `languages` and not `language`. But again, you don't really need to specify the source if the serializer field has the same name as the model field

Comment: @Ken4scholars yeah I have tried without a source as well it's giving that error.

Comment: the problem here is that you're trying to access the through model using the `languages` field - while this field actually maps directly to the `Language` instances (hence the error you're getting). you should add the correct related name that points to the `HelperLanguage` in your `languages = HelperLanguageSerializer...`  source.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships has an example of how to properly access it.